# Ionic v1 - $ionicModal - 'fromTemplateUrl' is undefined

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm following the documentation on how to implement the $ionicModel

http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/service/$ionicModal/

However, I'm getting the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '**fromTemplateUrl**' of undefined

My Controller:

```
.controller('barCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$ionicHistory', '$rootScope', '$ionicModal',
function ($scope, $stateParams, $ionicHistory, $rootScope, $cordovaInAppBrowser, $ionicModal) {
    /* Modal */
    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('/templates/bar.html', {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
    }).then(function (modal) {
        $scope.modal = modal;
    });
    $scope.openModal = function () {
        $scope.modal.show();
    };
    $scope.closeModal = function () {
        $scope.modal.hide();
    };
    // Cleanup the modal when we're done with it!
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        $scope.modal.remove();
    });
    // Execute action on hide modal
    $scope.$on('modal.hidden', function () {
        // Execute action
    });
    // Execute action on remove modal
    $scope.$on('modal.removed', function () {
        // Execute action
    });

}])
```

Template:

```
    <script id="bar.html" type="text/ng-template">
        <ion-modal-view>
            <ion-header-bar>
                <h1 class="title">My Modal title</h1>
            </ion-header-bar>
            <ion-content>
                Hello!
            </ion-content>
        </ion-modal-view>
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your order is wrong for dependencies.

Change this

```
.controller('barCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$ionicHistory', '$rootScope', '$ionicModal',
function ($scope, $stateParams, $ionicHistory, $rootScope, $cordovaInAppBrowser, $ionicModal)
```

to

```
.controller('barCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$ionicHistory', '$rootScope', '$ionicModal',
    function ($scope, $stateParams, $ionicHistory, $rootScope, $ionicModal)
```

Comment: Paresh Gami, thanks for your input. I do not understand this change. Why change barCtrl to AppCtrl ? and Why remove cordovaInAppBrowser? Thanks

Comment: Hey @Lernas, Paresh was just making an example here. You can go with your own ctrl, but just keep in mind that you have to inject dependencies in the same order, both in your array and then in the anonymous function !

Comment: yah that is just example so but renamed controller name. You add cordovaInAppBrowser but please add in sequence.

Comment: That was the issue, indeed. Thank you!